# Make a list of users who are not in another Mysql Table list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hard time to figure out how I can pull up a list of users who are not in the list of another mysql table.

Example : I have a list of all the users in my users table. My users table represents a list of all the employees in the company.

I have another table with the list of all the devices (laptop, iphone etc..). each device are assigned to a user.

I would like to know based on those 2 tables. The list of the users who does not have their name on the devices table ?

Is there a way to do this in PHP / MYSQL ?

I have a hard time to figure out how I can pull up a list of those users who does not appear at all on the device table ?

Comment: Something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98ce4/1

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the table and find the null value on the device table.
Example:
"user" table with user_id, user_name
"device" table with device_id, device_name, user_id

If you want to find out which users do not have a device, use this query:

```
select user_id, user_name
from user u 
left join device d on u.user_id=d.user_id
where d.user_id is null
```

This should show you all the users who does not have a corresponding record in the device table.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to exclude from your set of users the ones with devices using a `NOT IN` operator inside the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM device)
```